# How do you use logging in package which by default falls back to print in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I want to change my `print` statements of my package to using `logging`. So I will write my scripts like

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def func():
    logger.info("Calling func")
```

which is the recommended way?

However, many users do not initialize logging and hence will not see the output.

Is there a recommended way so that users who do not initialize logging can see `info` output, and those who explicitly set up logging do not get their specific configuration tampered with by my package?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, modules should never configure `logging` directly (and do other unsolicited changes to the shared STDOUT/STDERR either) as that's the realm of the module user. If the user wants the output, he should explicitly enable `logging` and then, and only then, your module should be allowed to *log*.

Bonus points if you provide an interface for explicitly enabling logging within your module so that the user doesn't have to explicitly change levels / disable loggers of your inner components if they're interested only in logging from their own code.

Of course, to keep using `logging` when a STDOUT/STDERR handler is not yet initialized you can use `logging.NullHandler` so all you have to do in your module is:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())  # initialize your logger with a NullHandler


def func():
    logger.info("Calling func")

func()  # (((crickets)))
```

Now you can continue using your `logger` throughout your module and until the user initializes `logging` your module won't trespass on the output, e.g.:

```
import your_module

your_module.func()  # (((crickets)))

import logging

logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)  
logging.info("Initialized!")  # INFO:root:Initialized!

your_module.func()  # INFO:your_module:Calling func
```

Of course, the actual logging format, level and other settings should also be in the realm of the user so if they change the format of the root log handler, it should be inherited by your module logger as well.